# How to use key generic type with typescript to build a dynamic table?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am building a dynamic table to show data from an array. I specify in columns array the columns head and the values will be related to the key of data array. In the following code, you can take a look to the component that call `Table`:

```
import { Table } from "../../../../design-system";
import { ColumnProp } from "../../../../design-system/table/table";

type Data = { rank: string; jockey: string; races: string };

const List = () => {
  const columns: ColumnProp<Data>[] = [
    { heading: "Rank", value: "rank" },
    { heading: "Jockey", value: "jockey" },
    { heading: "Races", value: "races" },
  ];

  const data = [
    { rank: "1", jockey: "Peter Smith", races: "23" },
    { rank: "2", jockey: "Mary King", races: "18" },
    { rank: "3", jockey: "Jack Parra", races: "15" },
  ];

  return <Table columns={columns} data={data} />;
};

export default List;
```

So, in the `Table` component, I have Props for the column and the table, they are generic. Everything seems to be fine but, I got error on `{d[c.value]}`.

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { colors } from "../theme/colors";

export type ColumnProp<T> = {
  heading: string;
  value: keyof T;
};

type TableProps<T> = {
  caption?: string;
  columns: Array<ColumnProp<T>>;
  data: Array<T>;
};

const Table = <T,>({ caption, columns, data }: TableProps<T>) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Caption>{caption}</Caption>
      <Thead>
        <tr>
          {columns.map((column: any) => (
            <Th>{column.heading}</Th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </Thead>
      <Tbody>
        {data.map((d, index) => (
          <tr>
            {columns.map((c, index) => (
              <Td>{d[c.value]}</Td> // <--- Here I got the error
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </Tbody>
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled.table({
  width: "100%",
  border: `1px solid ${colors.Black}`,
  borderCollapse: "collapse",
});

const Caption = styled.caption({
  marginBottom: "1rem",
});

const Thead = styled.thead({
  "& th": {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    verticalAlign: "top",
    padding: "5px",
  },
});

const Tbody = styled.thead({
  "& th": {
    verticalAlign: "top",
    padding: "5px",
  },
});

const Th = styled.th({
  border: `1px solid ${colors.Black}`,
  borderCollapse: "collapse",
});

const Td = styled.td({
  border: `1px solid ${colors.Black}`,
  borderCollapse: "collapse",
});

export default Table;
```

The error is:

[image]

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem. You can check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-volhard-q7eghz?file=/src/Table.tsx) for reference.

Comment: @tromgy is kind of weird but I found a solution making the value be ReactNode `<Td>{d[c.value] as ReactNode}</Td>`.